# PHP: Different charsets in POST and GET

Tags: php, string, utf-8, character-encoding, ascii

I'm having a problem with charsets being different in GET and POST-Requests in PHP. Here's the situation:

I've got a norwegian string. This string of course can have norwegian characters in it (i.e. "Ensjøsvingen"). If I pass this string via a GET-parameter, fetch it and let it count, it reports a strlen of 13 [which is correct]. If I pass this string via a POST-paramter, fetch it and let it count, it reports a strlen of 17.

When I convert the string to hexadecimal using printf, this is what comes out:

GET:
`45 6e 73 6a c3 b8 73 76 69 6e 67 65 6e`

POST:
`45 6e 73 6a 26 23 32 34 38 3b 73 76 69 6e 67 65 6e`

Obviously, POST is longer. My idea was that it was the charset so I let PHP tell me, what charsets the strings are in. PHP reports that the GET-String was in UTF-8 and the POST-String in ASCII (which is a subset of UTF-8). Converting ASCII to UTF-8 using iconv changes nothing in strlen.

Problem is, that I use that string to generate a SHA1-hash for later use (nothing critical where colissions are to be avoided, so SHA1 is totally fine), so I cannot use mb_*-functions to get the exact same hash no matter how the string was passed.

How I can solve this problem?

Comment: are you specifying the charset in your form? i.e. `<form enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8">`

Comment: @FuzzyTree Yes, I did that. Unfortunately, this doesn't change anything.

Comment: It is a bit of a work-around, but html_entity_decode handles many special characters in different formats, changing them to the proper html entity. If you send both strings through that function, do you get the same result? It should convert both to using &oslash;

Comment: @kainaw Using htmlentities/html_entity_decode is no option because the data already comes in the wrong way. This decoding process should take place before the form is being sent but that's not what I can do (using JS to pre-modify the form is no option).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am leaving my original answer below, because it does include some information that has helped me greatly in the past. After unhexing your provided outputs, however, the difference between your two strings is that the one from POST is encoded using HTML entities. Both strings are equivalent, however, you will need to use html_entity_decode (supply the UTF-8 in the encoding parameter) to get the results you need. I have left my answer from before, because a direct byte comparison may still fail after this for the reasons discussed below.

---

When PHP accepts input from the browser, it doesn't do anything with the character encoding. That being said, it does attempt, for GET parameters, to un-urlencode them for you. Depending on how the browser encodes UTF-8 strings, many characters have more than one encoding in UTF-8. There is one encoding for the complete character and even several different encodings that use a base character and combining diacritics or other marks to render the same result. For a Utf-8 aware language, this is no problem because all encodings for a character are supposed to be treated as equal, however, since PHP doesn't even try with character encodings you may simply be running into two different normalizations of the same string.

Many issues I have had in this regard were solved by using the [intl extension's Normalizer](http://php.net/manual/en/normalizer.normalize.php) so that I was always working with one normal form or the other and direct byte comparison (rather than UTF-8 aware character comparison) would yield the same results. That is an important thing to remember with all UTF-8 strings; strlen() and other PHP string functions not in the mb_string extension are not multibyte aware unless you turn on the overloading and so will give you byte counts rather than character counts when working with UTF-8.

To make a long story short, use the mb_string functions when working with UTF-8 and you should have better results or look into UTF-8 string normalization to make sure your byte comparisons will be equivalent when working with characters that have multiple encodings in UTF-8.

Comment: I marked this answer as correct. Using html_entity_decode with UTF-8 fixes this annoying problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: Thank you. I'm glad that you got the issue fixed. I should have unhexed first so I would'nt have had the annoying extra info at the end.